# Create link in Excel to Access Table

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb, ado

I'm creating a new Excel sheet in a C# project using OLEDB.

I then want to add a link to a certain data in a table in an Access Database using an SQL query. I know that it's possibly using Microsoft Interop and QueryTables.

Is this possible without Interop?